# How to test for an hold item name in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a command block that spawns an item in front of you if you are holding an item with a specific name. I've got these two working scripts;

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}]}

/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,­id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}]­}
```

but I can't get them together. The block should only look for an item in the active slot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually combine this into one command. Prior to 1.13, this would look like this:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
```

This will return an output if the player is holding a named diamond sword in the selected slot.

However, the above command has been completely deprecated in 1.13. `testfor` is now Bedrock only, and the `[r=]` selector has been changed. You also can't really do anything with this testfor anyway, all it does is give a redstone output. A better and updated version for Java Edition 1.13 would be something along the following lines:

```
/execute at @p[distance=..10, nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}] run <your item spawning command>
```

This command executes <your item spawning command> at the position of a player within 10 blocks that matches the SelectedItem NBT.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a script that only looks for the item name and only in the active slot.

Comment: @JaïrPaalman That's precisely what this does. The "SelectedItem" tag will look for an item in the player's hand regardless of what slot they have selected, so you don't need to have a command block for each hotbar slot.

Comment: Thanks, By the way, would you also happen to know how to summon an entity at the location of the player holding that item? I was told that /execute @p {the script} ~ ~ ~ 
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]} would work.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity @p[r=10,nbt={SelectedItem:...}]`

Comment: ^^^no. they removed ``r=`` and replaced it with ``distance=``, and in order to calculate anything before or after the specified number, you need to add ``..``, respectively. (eg. to find someone within 10 blocks radius, ``execute if entity @p[distance=..10,nbt={SelectedItem:...}]``)

Comment: @EarthToAccess I will update this properly when I get home tonight. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Unionhawk What happened? :D

Comment: @RudolfJelin https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/232198/3 :)

Comment: @Unionhawk Phew. I was afraid you hadn't gotten home yet. :–) Jokes aside, thanks, especially since now all similar questions got closed as duplicates of this one.

Comment: It should be `execute ... run <your item spawning command>`, not `execute ... <your item spawning command>`

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two dataTags you need to move the `tag` compound from first command into the inventory item compound in the second:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,­id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}]}
```

**Note**: This will only test true if the item is in slot 0 and it is also the selected item.

You can use the [SelectedItem tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#NBT_structure) instead of the SelectedItemSlot tag.  This will allow you to target any player who currently has the specified item selected no matter which slot it is in:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
```

---

As of 1.9 you can use [scoreboard add tag command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags_commands) to tag the player holding the specific item.

```
scoreboard players tag @a add <tagName> {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
```

This allows you to target the players within another command.  Lets make the players with the selected sword say hello:

```
/execute @a[tag=<tagName>] ~ ~ ~ say hello
```

You could use this tag in the item summon commands.

Then to remove the tag from all player:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove <tagName>
```

---

If you want to test for any player holding *any item* with the correct name, simply omit the id portion of the dataTag:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a data pack, for better performance, a [predicate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Predicate) should be used to detect holding an item in the main hand.

Predicates are more efficient than `/execute if entity @s[nbt=…]` or `/execute if data entity @s {…}` because NBT checks on players are heavy on performance.

Predicates go in the `/data/<namespace>/predicates` folder of your data pack.

A sample predicate for this purpose would look like this:

```
{
  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
  "entity": "this",
  "predicate": {
    "equipment": {
      "mainhand": {
        "items": ["minecraft:diamond_sword"],
        "nbt": "{CustomItemTag:1b}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}}
```

Would work but a better way to do it would be to use scoreboard objectives with stats ex-

```
/scoreboard objectives add ItemHold stat.useItem.minecraft.diamond.sword
```

I have tested it and it works so try that...

Comment: `stat.useItem.minecraft.diamond.sword` increases when you hit a mob/player with a diamond sword, not when you hold it. This answer also doesn't account for the item being named.